# Firebase post successful signup redirecting before sending verification email

Tags: javascript, firebase, promise, firebase-authentication

I am chaining promises here:

1. First to send verification email
2. Then update user profile information
3. Then redirect user to my app's dashboard page

I was expecting the .then calls to happen only when the previous ones have finished execution. But instead, redirection is happening before sending verification email or updating profile. Below is the piece of code responsible for the same:

```
function authorizeWithFireBase(email,displayName,password,photoURL){
    var user = null;
    var failText = document.getElementById("signup-invalid-message");

    //NULLIFY EMPTY ARGUMENTS
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        arguments[i] = arguments[i] ? arguments[i] : null;
    }
    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(function () {
        user = auth.currentUser;
        user.sendEmailVerification();
    })
    .then(function () {
        user.updateProfile({
            displayName: displayName,
            photoURL: photoURL
        });
    })
    .then(function () {
        window.location.replace("/path/to/private/app/dashboard/page");
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        if(error.code == 'auth/weak-password') {
            failText.innerHTML = "Please set a complex password!"
        }
        else {
            failText.innerHTML = error.message;
        }
    });
    console.log('Validation link was sent to ' + email + '.');
}
```

I tried switching the

> .then(function() {...})

to

> .then( () => function() {...})

but then none of the 3 .then() part get executed.

What am I doing wrong and how can I chain these promises to carry all 3 of the above mentioned steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to return a promise from within each `then()` to be able to chain them. Lucky for you [`sendEmailVerification()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#sendEmailVerification) and [`updateProfile()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#updateProfile) both return promises, so it's a simple change:

```
auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
.then(function () {
    user = auth.currentUser;
    return user.sendEmailVerification();
})
.then(function () {
    return user.updateProfile({
        displayName: displayName,
        photoURL: photoURL
    });
})
.then(function () {
    window.location.replace("/path/to/private/app/dashboard/page");
})
.catch(function(error) {
    if(error.code == 'auth/weak-password') {
        failText.innerHTML = "Please set a complex password!"
    }
    else {
        failText.innerHTML = error.message;
    }
});
```

Comment: I guess the updateProfile still did not work as the verification email did not have display name value set which comes as part of the template. Anything that I am missing here?

Comment: If you want to ensure you have the latest user data be sure to call [`user.reload()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#reload). But that's unrelated to the fact that you need to return promises to ensure the callbacks execute in order.

Comment: My bad, I am updating profile post sending the verification email, so the display name should have been empty as expected. And yes, thanks for the returns in promises. It was much needed :)